# Visual Studio 2022 (Windows) MUAI project does not show iOS simulators

Tags: visual-studio-2022

Really hoping someone can help me here. I have done my exhaustive best to resolve the following issue.

In a nutshell; I do not see any iOS simulators for MAUI projects in VS2022 (Windows).

[image: No iOS simulators]

[image: Exception during debug]

**Mac Setup:**
[image: XCode version]

I can verify that my VS2022 connects to my Mac;

[image: VS2022 to Mac connection]

This is the project type I select & get no iOS simulator;
[image: VS2022 MAUI project selection]

**My Setup;**
Windows 10, running VS2022;

[image: VS Studio installed options #1]

[image: VS Studio installed options #2]

[image: VS Studio installed options #3]

[image: VS2022 Xamarin options]

Strangely: iOS simulators are available when I select an iOS Xamarin project type in VS2022]
[image: iOS simulators are available when I select an iOS Xamarin project type in VS2022]

Please help. Much appreciated.

These are all the articles I have researched;

[LINK 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73021473/net-maui-unable-to-debug-ios-on-simulator-or-phone),

[LINK 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/remote-simulator?view=net-maui-7.0),

[LINK 3](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/ios-simulator-in-visual-studio-2022/1502586),

[LINK 4](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/ios-simulators-do-not-appear-for-running-project/1242725),

[LINK 5](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/10085).

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? Having the same issue.

Comment: @FinniusFrog hope my answer below helps.

Answer (score 0):

The bug was resolved following a Visual Studio update from Microsoft. Sharing the updated version below & the screenshot of the available simulators;

[image: Updated Visual Studio 2022]
[image: iOS simulator available now]