code object is not signed at all on .net MAUI
I am trying to debug my MAUI app on a real iOS device for push notifications. I have a remote mac connection to my mac book[Sonoma 14.5], Visual Studio 2022 [Version 17.9.7], Xcode [15.2] iOS Device[17.5] and no matter what I do I get this error : code object is not signed at all

Tried removing every sub directory in resource folder
Tried using both Auto. and Manual Provisioning. Even logged in via API instead of email and pass to apple developer and still no luck.
Removed everything related to push notifications to simplify the certificate and provisioning profiles

here is the build log I get every time no matter what changes I make.
Build started at 1:54 AM...
1>------ Build started: Project: MyAPP, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>Executing SayHello Task to establish a connection to a Remote Server. 
1>          Properties: 
1>              SessionId=***, 
1>              Addresss=192.168..., 
1>              SshPort=22, 
1>              TcpPort=..., 
1>              User=***, 
1>              AppName=MyAPP,
1>              VisualStudioProcessId=14340,
1>              ContinueOnDisconnected=False
1>Detected signing identity:
1>  Code Signing Key: "Apple Development: ...
1>  Provisioning Profile: "VS: com.i...
1>  Bundle Id: com.i...
1>  App Id: ***.com.i..
1>Skipping analyzers to speed up the build. You can execute 'Build' or 'Rebuild' command to run analyzers.
1>E:\...
...
...
...
1>--skip-unresolved true  --notrimwarn --custom-data "LinkerOptionsFile=obj/Debug/net8.0-ios/ios-arm64/custom-linker-options.txt" --custom-data DisableMarkingOfCopyAssemblies=true --verbose -b --disable-opt unusedtypechecks --enable-serialization-discovery
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.iOS.Windows.Sdk\17.2.8053\tools\msbuild\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.After.targets(364,3): warning MT4189: The class 'PassKit.PKDisbursementAuthorizationController' will not be registered it has been removed from the iOS SDK.
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.iOS.Windows.Sdk\17.2.8053\tools\msbuild\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.After.targets(364,3): warning MT4189: The class 'PassKit.PKDisbursementAuthorizationControllerDelegate' will not be registered it has been removed from the iOS SDK.
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.iOS.Windows.Sdk\17.2.8053\tools\msbuild\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.After.targets(364,3): warning MT4178: The class 'NewsstandKit.NKAssetDownload' will not be registered because the NewsstandKit framework has been removed from the iOS SDK.
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.iOS.Windows.Sdk\17.2.8053\tools\msbuild\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.After.targets(364,3): warning MT4178: The class 'NewsstandKit.NKLibrary' will not be registered because the NewsstandKit framework has been removed from the iOS SDK.
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.iOS.Windows.Sdk\17.2.8053\tools\msbuild\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.After.targets(364,3): warning MT4178: The class 'NewsstandKit.NKIssue' will not be registered because the NewsstandKit framework has been removed from the iOS SDK.
1>/usr/bin/mdimport bin/Debug/net8.0-ios/ios-arm64/device-builds/iphone13.1-17.5.1/
1>Tool /usr/bin/codesign execution finished (exit code = 1).
1>/Users/user/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/MyAPP/.../bin/Debug/net8.0-ios/ios-arm64/device-builds/iphone13.1-17.5.1/MyAPP.app: code object is not signed at all
1>In subcomponent: /Users/user/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/MyAPP/.../bin/Debug/net8.0-ios/ios-arm64/device-builds/iphone13.1-17.5.1/MyAPP.app/System.Runtime.Intrinsics.dll
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.iOS.Sdk\17.2.8053\tools\msbuild\iOS\Xamarin.Shared.targets(2257,3): error : /usr/bin/codesign exited with code 1:
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.iOS.Sdk\17.2.8053\tools\msbuild\iOS\Xamarin.Shared.targets(2257,3): error : /Users/user/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/MyAPP/.../bin/Debug/net8.0-ios/ios-arm64/device-builds/iphone13.1-17.5.1/MyAPP.app: code object is not signed at all
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.iOS.Sdk\17.2.8053\tools\msbuild\iOS\Xamarin.Shared.targets(2257,3): error : In subcomponent: /Users/user/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/MyAPP/.../bin/Debug/net8.0-ios/ios-arm64/device-builds/iphone13.1-17.5.1/MyAPP.app/System.Runtime.Intrinsics.dll
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.iOS.Sdk\17.2.8053\tools\msbuild\iOS\Xamarin.Shared.targets(2257,3): error : Failed to codesign '/Users/user/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/MyAPP/.../bin/Debug/net8.0-ios/ios-arm64/device-builds/iphone13.1-17.5.1/MyAPP.app': /Users/user/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/MyAPP/.../bin/Debug/net8.0-ios/ios-arm64/device-builds/iphone13.1-17.5.1/MyAPP.app: code object is not signed at all
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.iOS.Sdk\17.2.8053\tools\msbuild\iOS\Xamarin.Shared.targets(2257,3): error : In subcomponent: /Users/user/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/MyAPP/.../bin/Debug/net8.0-ios/ios-arm64/device-builds/iphone13.1-17.5.1/MyAPP.app/System.Runtime.Intrinsics.dll
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.iOS.Sdk\17.2.8053\tools\msbuild\iOS\Xamarin.Shared.targets(2257,3): error : 
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.iOS.Sdk\17.2.8053\tools\msbuild\iOS\Xamarin.Shared.targets(2257,3): error :
1>Done building project "MyAPP.csproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Build completed at 1:55 AM and took 41.399 seconds ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy completed at 1:55 AM and took 41.399 seconds ==========



see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/78463367/3392605

@MustafaMutasim, Thanks. I've already seen your post before and tried it multiple times. cleared cache folder from Mac and windows multiple times, still no luck

Welcome, did you success before? or this is your first try? because many time when I install the new updates for Visual Studio debugging is broken, till now it's stable since 3 months, I'm using preview version since last year, my version 17.11.0 Preview 1.0

[@Farshad Nabizadeh] I've updated my answer.

@MustafaMutasim no. never! but now because of push notification test I have to. before that I was using simulator. and I can also generate signed ipa for release. just debugging has this problem

check my previous answer again, I’ve updated it now

check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/73051263

@MustafaMutasim Great, Ill check preview version

Will the error still occur when using the latest version of VS preview on mac?

@MustafaMutasim - upgraded everything to latest version (vs preview on windows, .net 8.0.301 on both mac and windows, switched to dev kit pre-release on vscode ...) but still I cannot sign the app using vscode or visual studio remote or local vs for mac.

@ShuowenHe-MSFT tried that, but due to retirement of VS for mac I couldn't find any preview version newer than my installed stable version or change the update channel to preview within visual studio.

What is the system version of your iOS device? Have you tried to deploy the Maui project on other versions of iOS devices?

@ShuowenHe-MSFT it is 17.5.1. I have to find other device that is not updated. no luck so far.
